# What does it mean to have "powerful" chakra?

Tags: naruto

Tobi once stated that he (referring to Madara) was born with an especially strong chakra.

That is the only time we ever hear about the "power" of chakra! We know that one can have a lot of chakra, and we know he can learn to utilize his chakra efficiently. But what does "strong" chakra mean?

Does it make his techniques more powerful than other, less power chakra users? Does it mean that his YinYang balance is naturally stronger? Does it make him live longer?

Comment: Perhaps it refers to his physical energy at the time of birth

Comment: @ChetterHummin: Well, I could understand if he was a Senju, as high Physical energy is more common there...

Comment: True, but it could happen for other families as well

Comment: This could also just mean that he has more chakra than most people. Especially if you're reading/watching a translated/subbed version, it might not translate perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it's much like "The Force is strong with this one" :P

From [Naruto wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra), we can learn that

> Normal chakra is a form of energy all living individuals naturally
>   produce to some degree. Contained in the "chakra coils" that mainly
>   surround and connect to each chakra-producing organ, the energy
>   circulates throughout the body in a network called the "chakra
>   circulatory system" (similar to the cardiovascular system).

And, later in the same article, it is stated:

> Chakra is the resulting form of energy when two other forms of energy
>   are mixed together. The two energies are referred to as "physical
>   energy" and "spiritual energy". **Physical energy is collected from the
>   body's cells** and can be increased through training, stimulants, and
>   exercise. Spiritual energy is derived from the mind's consciousness
>   (i.e. the soul) and can be increased through studying, meditation, and
>   experience. **Having these two energies become more powerful will
>   in-turn make the created chakra more powerful. Therefore, practising a
>   technique repeatedly will build-up experience, building up one's
>   spiritual energy, and thus allowing more chakra to be created. As a
>   result, the ninja is able to do that same technique with more power.
>   This same cycle applies for physical energy**, except this time, instead
>   of doing things like meditation, the ninja could, say, do push-ups.

emphasis mine.

So, I think that saying that someone is born with "strong chakra" means that the physical part of that person's chakra (the one that he has from birth) is better... developed (or maybe advanced), comparing to other people. Whether this individual will further develop this natural...boon, depends on him.

This estimation of chakra strength can also be different depending on who to compare with. For example, one can be compared with other members of the same clan, or shinobi of the same village, or maybe all shinobi in general.